# How can I get what is in database to show up in the form?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a table that is labeled categories. It holds the id,name,sub_id

I have a form that is displaying categorys and subcategories. 
Here is the php/html to display the dropdowns where category and sub cat can be selected.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 input-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Category</label>
    <?php 
      $tr = array();
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $tr[$category['id']] = $category['name'];
      }
      echo form_dropdown('category_id', $tr, '', 'class="form-control tip" id="category_id" style="width:100%;"');
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 input-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Sub Category</label>
    <select id="sub_category" name="sub_category" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery to select the subcategory

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $('#category_id').on('change', function (e) {
    $('#sub_category').val('').trigger('change');
  });
  $( "#sub_category" ).select2({        
    ajax: {
      placeholder: 'Select a Category',
      url: "<?= base_url(); ?>panel/settings/getCategoriesAjax/0",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term,
          category_id: $('#category_id').val(),
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
  });
}
```

It is working perfectly to submit the data to the database and update the required table with the category and subcategory ID.

I cannot figure out how to pull the category ID and subcategory ID back and have them be the selected value when the form is "edited'

I'm looking to do someting like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 input-field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Category</label>
    <?php 
      $tr = array();
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $tr[$category['id']] = $category['name'];
      }
      echo form_dropdown('category_id', $tr, $result, 'class="form-control tip" id="category_id" style="width:100%;"');
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can't figure out what the $result would need to be. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
<?php foreach($categorylist as $category) { ?>
  <option value="<?=$category['id'];?>"><?=$category['name']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

in the controller:

```
public function user(){
    $this->load->model('usersmodel');
    $data['categorylist'] = $this->usersmodel->get_categories_list();
    $this->load->view('users/layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('users/registration',$data);
    $this->load->view('users/layouts/footer');
}
```

In your model:

```
public function get_category_list(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Then after you get the id for the category you can call your ajax function, I hope it helped you :)